# Cross Platform System Usage Metrics

Tags: c, measurement, performance

Is there a cross platform C API that can be used to get system usage metrics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've worked with [libstatgrab](http://www.i-scream.org/libstatgrab/) before.  Gets you some pretty useful system statistics for the main Unix-like variants and Windows through Cygwin (supposedly - never tried).  Different OS's work so differently - especially when it comes to usage metrics - it may be challenging to get what you want.  Even something as simple sounding as "free memory" can be tricky to act on in a cross-platform way.  Perhaps if you narrow things down a bit, maybe we can find something.

Comment: libstatgrab looks pretty cool.  I wonder if it is currently well maintained.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately not.

The C standard is pretty much limited to dynamic allocation, string manipulation, math and text I/O.  Once you get beyond that, you need OS APIs which by definition are OS specific and not cross platform.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the metrics you want to collect, you may want to consider looking at [PCP](http://oss.sgi.com/projects/pcp/) (Performance Co-Pilot). This is an open-source performance framework, originally developed at Silicon Graphics, which collects and collates a vast number of possible metrics from a vast number of sources, and lets you monitor them from anywhere.

Basically PCP would involve adding another 'layer' into your system -- for example, you might monitor a distributed cluster of mixed-OS machines, each with PCP installed locally; a set of 'agents' collect the performance data on each machine, and your code could then use libpcp to collect those metrics as required.

It's hard to say without knowing your exact usage scenario (if you're talking about something running seamlessly on end-users' machines, PCP may not suit but if you want to monitor machines which you control, and are happy to run the PCP service on them, it's an awesome solution).

We use PCP very happily to collect metrics from Windows and Linux boxes, as well as internal metrics from our application, and log them all centrally, report on them, monitor trends, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The good old [SNMP](http://www.net-snmp.org/) provides C libraries for the client and server side. If you prefer something newer you should try [Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/). They have [Node Exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter) ready to use and the client libraries for many languages including [C](https://github.com/digitalocean/prometheus-client-c).

Also note that PCP (mentioned in Cowan's answer) supports the OpenMetrics standard since version 4, so if you decide to use Prometheus as the metric data collector extending PCP or writing a custom Prometheus client are better solutions that SNMP which also supported by Prometheus through [SNMP Exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/snmp_exporter), but more difficult to set up due to the way it handles MIBs and authentication.